# How to compare a const string reference to a string pointer?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, reference, compare

Hi this is my 1st post :)

I am very new to C++ programming and do not fully understand the implementations of string references and pointers. I have spent over an hour scouring the web to find out how I convert one of these two strings to be 'comparable', but everything I've found has had to do with either just comparing 2 normal strings, or a const string& and a char*, or something slightly different.
I have read string wikipedias and everything I have thought of to try and figure this out, but I simply do Not know what is going on.

In short, I need to compare strings using the '<' operator.  Ex: " if (foo< bar) std::cout << "foo is less than bar\n"; "

The way I understand it from "http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operators/"
both the left-hand-side and the rhs of the operator have to be const string&

```
bool operator<  (const string& lhs, const string& rhs);
bool operator<  (const char*   lhs, const string& rhs);
bool operator<  (const string& lhs, const char*   rhs);
```

In my code, I have a string value that is already a const string&, and a string value that is a string*.

**The problem is**, when I try to compare a const string& to a string*, I get an error.

I am new to this and barely understand what a const string& is, and why I cannot compare it to a string*.

Could you please help me in finding a way to compare these two strings for my BST insertion?

Here is my BST class

```
  class BST
{
    public:
        BST();
        ~BST();

        void insertContent(const string& word, const string& definition);
        void deleteContent(string* word);
        const string* getContent(const string& word);

    private:
        class Node
        {
            public:
                Node(string* word, string* definition)
                {left=NULL; right=NULL; m_word=word; m_definition=definition;}

                Node* left;
                Node* right;
                string* m_word;
                string* m_definition;
        };
```

Here is the insert function where I need help comparing strings

```
void BST::insertContent(const string& word, const string& definition)
{
    Node* ptr = root;
    //Node* entry = new Node(word, definition);

    if (root == NULL)
    {
        root = new Node(word, definition);
        return;
    }

    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        const string& curwor = ptr->m_word; /*I was thinking of making my own const string& out of ptr->m_word but it didn't work. */

        **if (word < ptr->m_word)**
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/

Comment: 'const' stands for constant. If you declared as a 'const', it cannot be modified. If you can change value of it, that must be a variable.

Comment: Dereference the pointer: `if (word < *(ptr->m_word))`. You could ask this question in five lines of code.

Comment: You can compare two string using '==' or '!=' for equality. You'd better not to use other operators bu use 'compare' method instead.

Comment: A string is just an abstraction for a char[]. In fact, c++ just gives you a type string and convenient function to manipulate it, but under the curtain, it is just treated as a char array. Therefore, you can still use pointers to parse a string like you would do with a char[].

Answer (score 0):

According to your question,The sample code is below:

```
std::string test1 = "test1";
std::string test2 = "test2";
const std::string &test3 = test1;
std::string * point_str = &test2;
if (test3 > (*point_str))
{
    std::cout << "The test1 is bigger" << std::endl;
}
else
{
std::cout << "The test2 is bigger" << std::endl;
}
```

The string * point should use as **(*point)**. Have look at two good C++ book: effective C++ and more effective C++.